# Stopwatch c# game

Tags: c#, maze, stopwatch

I'm trying to create MAZE game in C# and I'm a bit confused with making a stopwatch (I want it to be started with the start of level and to be stoped with a win) to print time of playing a level. I can't understand where and how to add it properly. So here is my main game logic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


namespace Labyrinth
{
    class Level
    {
        private Field gameField;
        private Player player;

        public Thread keyThread;
        public PressedKey key;

        public enum PressedKey
        {
            Left, Right, Up, Down, Fire, None
        }

        public bool Game;


        public Level(int level)
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Game = true;
            StartThread();
            new LevelLoader(level).LoadField(out gameField, out player);
        }

        public void UpdateField()
        {
            PlayerAction();
            PutCharactersOnField();
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        private void PutCharactersOnField()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gameField.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < gameField.Width; x++)
                {
                    if (!(gameField[x, y] is Wall) && !((gameField[x, y] is Key)) && !((gameField[x, y] is Door)))
                    {
                        gameField[x, y] = new Empty();
                    }
                }
            }
            gameField[player.X, player.Y] = player;
        }

        private void PlayerAction()
        {
            int dx = 0, dy = 0;
            switch (key)
            {
                case PressedKey.Up:
                    dy = -1;
                    break;
                case PressedKey.Down:
                    dy = 1;
                    break;
                case PressedKey.Left:
                    dx = -1;
                    break;
                case PressedKey.Right:
                    dx = 1;
                    break;
            }

            player.Rotate(dx, dy);
            if (gameField.CanMakeStep(player.X + dx, player.Y + dy))
            {
                player.MakeStep(dx, dy);
                key = PressedKey.None;
            }
        }


        public void PrintLevel()
        {
            gameField.Print();
            player.Draw();
            LivesMessage();
            if (Door.count == 0)
            {
                Win();
            };
        }

        private void Win()
        {
            Game = false;
            keyThread.Interrupt();
            Console.Beep();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("COngrats! You win");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Help WinMenu = new Help();
            WinMenu.Menu();
        }

        private void ConsoleMessage(int x, int y, string message)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write(message);
        }

    

        private void LivesMessage()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            ConsoleMessage(0, gameField.Height + 1, "Doors Left: " + Door.count);
            ConsoleMessage(0, gameField.Height + 2, "Keys Left: " + Key.count);
        }

        private void StartThread()
        {
            key = PressedKey.None;
            keyThread = new Thread(KeysInput);
            keyThread.Start();
        }

        private void KeysInput()
        {
            while (Game)
            {
                var currntKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

                switch (currntKey.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.W:
                        key = PressedKey.Up;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        key = PressedKey.Up;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.A:
                        key = PressedKey.Left;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        key = PressedKey.Left;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D:
                        key = PressedKey.Right;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        key = PressedKey.Right;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.S:
                        key = PressedKey.Down;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        key = PressedKey.Down;
                        break;
                    default:
                        key = PressedKey.None;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very new in such a topic, so I'd be grateful for any help. Where and how I can add a **stopwatch**??
Should I make a stopwatch separated class or just some method?

```
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); 
    stopWatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Console.ReadKey();
 
    Console.WriteLine();
    stopWatch.Stop();]
 
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine($"{ts.Seconds:00}:{ts.Milliseconds:00}");
 
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Careful on using stopWatch.Elapsed, I think you want: 
`Console.WriteLine($"{ts.TotalSeconds:00}:{ts.Milliseconds:00}");`

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `Stopwatch` at all for this, as that class is really for diagnostics (The clue is it's namespace `System.Diagnostics`).

You're interested in how long a player takes to play your game, which can be done just fine with `DateTime`. You can compare 2 of those with `Subtract` which returns you an instance of `TimeSpan` - this you can use to determine how many seconds/minutes/whatever the player took to play the game.

Store a `startTime` when the level is created (I assume this is the point at which the game "starts")

```
private DateTime startTime;

public Level(int level)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    Game = true;
    StartThread();
    new LevelLoader(level).LoadField(out gameField, out player);
    startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Then when the game ends compare it to `DaweTime.Now` (I assume this is inside `Win` but may be elsewhere as wll):

```
private void Win()
{
    Game = false;
    keyThread.Interrupt();
    Console.Beep();
    Console.Clear();

    var timeTaken = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(startTime);
    Console.WriteLine($"You took {timeTaken.TotalSeconds} seconds");

    Console.WriteLine("COngrats! You win");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Help WinMenu = new Help();
    WinMenu.Menu();
}
```

Comment: I prefer `StopWatch` for measuring time, and only for the slim chance a user changes time of pc, or daylight saving

Comment: Just as a personal habit (and cause it is *faster*) I normally use `DateTime.UtcNow`. With `DateTime.Now` time zone informations has to be computed and is not needed (cause it's used only for calculations).

Comment: @RandRandom: Great, but if your system doesn't support a high performance query counter [it falls back to `DateTime.UtcNow`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs#L142)

Comment: @Oliver I _always_ use `UtcNow` - quite why I wrote `Now` I have no idea!